# Rating 1.5V 50mA (MAX) what does it means?

Tags: batteries, amperage, power-consumption

I have an optic mouse that has in its specifications this:
1.5V -- 50mA (MAX).

What does it means? Does it means it consumes 50 miliamps an hour? or the maximum consumption would be 50mA depending on usage?

Thank you,

Matias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.5V is the required supply voltage. It should be like this +/- some tolerated deviance. the 50mA MAX is the **maximum** current the manufacturer of the mouse is promising will be drawn by it under any (functioning) conditions. These two specifications are necessary for choosing the right power supply for the device - it should be able to provide this maximum current with the specified voltage.

Comment: Ok, so how can I calculate for example the amount of time my 1.5V battery will last?

Comment: The battery's charge is usually given in (milli)ampere-hour units. So if it says 1000mAh, it means that it can provide 1000mA for 1 hour. Or 50mA for 1000/50=20 hours (roughly, of course). Since 50mA is the maximum, it's the worst case scenario.

Comment: Right, ok so if the mouse uses 50mA all the time then a battery of 1000mA would give 20 hours of operation. Thanks!

Comment: @Matias The mouse will NOT use 50mA all the time, it says "maximum" for a reason. It's just if you wanted to use a 1.5V coin cell battery, those cant put out 50mA, so you need to ensure the battery you provide can indeed provide the required current. If the battery cannot supply the required current, the voltage levels will sag, and the device will malfunction.

Answer (score 0):

It's a maximum peak current draw from the 1.5V battery.

You cannot draw useful conclusions about how long a battery will last under normal operating conditions from this information- a well-designed mouse will go into a low-consumption standby state when it has not been used for a while and will draw a small fraction of the active current.